# How do I truncate text and display a read more button in React if the text goes past a certain amount of lines?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am building a Notes app in React and I am storing the notes in Firestore. I want to show a "Read More" button if the content I am reading from Firestore goes past three lines. If it doesn't then I don't want to show a "Read More" button,

Also using Tailwind for styling and I know they have a line camp plugin and class called "truncate" but I don't know how to implement it with the conditionally rendered button. So any help on how to implement this would be appreciated it. Here's my code for the text that needs to be truncated.

```
<div>
   <p className="break-words text-xl">{note?.noteContent}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using CSS (or Tailwind) to truncate to a specific line is a good approach. You then need to use JavaScript to detect whether your text has been truncated, so that you can decide to show/hide the "Read more" button. This can be done by comparing your element's `scrollHeight` to its `offsetHeight`.

- The `scrollHeight` measures the height of an element's content, including anything hidden by overflow ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight))
- The `offsetHeight` measures an element's rendered height, which excludes anything hidden by overflow ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight))

So, if the `scrollHeight` is greater than the `offsetHeight`, we know our element has some overflow. In this case, that our text has been truncated. To use these values in React, we'll want to use a `ref` and the `useLayoutEffect` hook.

### Full example code

This assumes you *just* want a "Read more" button. I'll include another example with a "Read less" option.

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

const useTruncatedElement = ({ ref }) => {
  const [isTruncated, setIsTruncated] = useState(false);
  const [isReadingMore, setIsReadingMore] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const { offsetHeight, scrollHeight } = ref.current || {};

    if (offsetHeight && scrollHeight && offsetHeight < scrollHeight) {
      setIsTruncated(true);
    } else {
      setIsTruncated(false);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return {
    isTruncated,
    isReadingMore,
    setIsReadingMore,
  };
};

export default function Note() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const { isTruncated, isReadingMore, setIsReadingMore } = useTruncatedElement({
    ref,
  });

  // Code to get your note content...

  return (
    <div>
      <p ref={ref} className={`break-words text-xl ${!isReadingMore && 'line-clamp-3'}`}>
        {note?.noteContent}
      </p>
      {isTruncated && !isReadingMore && (
        <button onClick={() => setIsReadingMore(true)}>
          Read more
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Code walkthrough

The `useTruncatedElement` hook works out if your paragraph has been truncated, as explained above. It also returns some state that determines whether the "Read more" button has already been clicked. That way we can expand the text by removing the `line-clamp-3` class, and hide the button after it's been clicked (or change the text to "Read less").

### Tailwind's line clamp plugin

The plugin takes care of the truncation with one class in the form `line-clamp-{n}`. It adds the following CSS to the element (which you can add if you're not using tailwind):

```css
.line-clamp-{n} {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: {n};
}
```

To install the plugin:

`npm install -D @tailwindcss/line-clamp`

or

`yarn add -D @tailwindcss/line-clamp`

Then add it to the plugins array in your `tailwind.config.cjs` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp")],
};
```

### Show more / Show less

If you want a toggle so that the user could truncate the text again after having expanded it (a kind of Show more / Show less scenario) then you could return a toggle function from the hook instead:

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

const useTruncatedElement = ({ ref }) => {
  const [isTruncated, setIsTruncated] = useState(false);
  const [isShowingMore, setIsShowingMore] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const { offsetHeight, scrollHeight } = ref.current || {};

    if (offsetHeight && scrollHeight && offsetHeight < scrollHeight) {
      setIsTruncated(true);
    } else {
      setIsTruncated(false);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  const toggleIsShowingMore = () => setIsShowingMore(prev => !prev);

  return {
    isTruncated,
    isShowingMore,
    toggleIsShowingMore,
  };
};

export default function Note() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const { isTruncated, isShowingMore, toggleIsShowingMore } = useTruncatedElement({
    ref,
  });

  // Code to get your note content...

  return (
    <div>
      <p ref={ref} className={`break-words text-xl ${!isShowingMore && 'line-clamp-3'}`}>
        {note?.noteContent}
      </p>
      {isTruncated && (
        <button onClick={toggleIsShowingMore}>
          {isShowingMore ? 'Show less' : 'Show more'}
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a character limit on the text with something like the following.

```
const charMax = 40

<p>`${note?.noteContent.substring(0, charMax)}...`</p>
// This just takes the string from the beginning to charMax (40)
```

And then something like

```
if (note?.noteContent.length > charMax) {
  // Render button logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach using NextJS and Tailwind for the case that there are several elements that need to be toggled individually.

```
const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState([]); // Array where we keep the unique id's of the toggled entries

// We check if the actual id already exists in the isToggled array so that we know if it needs to be added or removed.

const ToggleFullView = (id) => {
  setIsToggled((prev) => {
    if (prev.includes(id)) {
      return prev.filter((item) => item !== id);
    } else {
      return [...prev, id];
    }
  });
};
```

On the html side I check if the text is larger than 200 characters and show the Read more/less link and if the array isToggled contains the specific id, I add the line-clamp-5 Tailwind attribute that actually truncates the text.
On click on read more I remove the line-clamp attribute from the paragraph.

```
<div>
  <p className={`${!isToggled.includes(review.id) && 'line-clamp-5'}`}>
    {review.feedback}
  </p>
  {text.length > 200 && (
    <span
      onClick={() => ToggleFullView(id)}
    >
      {isToggled.includes(id) ? 'Read less' : 'Read more'}
    </span>
  )}
</div>
```